# Query to remove last result using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am having trouble parsing an xml file . A sample is below.

```
<G_LOG>
  <LINE>9206</LINE>
  <TEXT>Generating 
</TEXT>
</G_LOG>
<G_LOG>
  <LINE>9207</LINE>
  <TEXT>Inserted Actual
</TEXT>
```

O.K , so this is just a snapshot of thousands of nodes in the file. I need to search for the TEXT "Inserted Actual" and not only remove this node , but the previous node as well. So it would find the text on line 9207 and remove 9206 as well. (removing everything in the above snippet)

I can search for the lines I want to remove .

```
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
 var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("G_LOG")
         where c.Element("TEXT").Value.Contains("Inserted Actual")
         select (string)c.Element("LINE");
 foreach (string name in q)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Actuals Success on ID : " + name);           
 }
```

But I am unsure of how to obtain the previous node and remove it as well (without buckets of code)?.

Comment: Are you *just* trying to remove the `LINE` element, or the whole `G_LOG` element?

Comment: How about [PreviousSibling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.previoussibling.aspx) or [PreviousNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.previousnode.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elementsToRemove =
    from logElement in xml.Descendants("G_LOG")
    where logElement.Element("TEXT").Value.Contains("Inserted Actual")
    from element in new[] { logElement, logElement.PreviousNode }
    select element;

foreach(var element in elementsToRemove.ToList())
{
    element.Remove();
}
```

A couple of things to note:

1. The second `from` flattens out each node and its previous node into one sequence
2. The `.ToList()` eagerly evaluates the query, ensuring we don't remove a node while evaluating

Answer (score 1):

```
XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load("c:\\temp.xml");
 var q = xmlDoc.Descendants("G_LOG").Where(c=>c.Element("TEXT").Value.Contains("Inserted Actual")).Select(d=>d.Element("LINE"));
foreach(XElement elm in q)
{
if(elm.Parent.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count()!=0)
elm.Parent.PreviousNode.Remove();
elm.Parent.RemoveNodes();
}
```